# wrong result on adition of numbers larger than epsilon using numpy.float128

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Considering that epsilon is the smallest number that you **can** add to one.

I'm getting 1 instead of 1+epsilon when I perform the addition and print the result.

I've implemented a `getEpsilon` function. I added a `print` statement for debugging.

The function is implemented as follows:

```
def getEpsilon():
    a = np.float128(1)
    b = np.float128(1)
    c = np.float128(2)
    while a + b != a:
        b = b / c
        d = a+b
        print (F"b={b:3.50f}, d={d:3.50f}")
    return b * c
```

After some iterations of the while loop the value of `d` is just 1, but `a + b != a` still evaluates as True.

This is the output:

```
b=0.5000000000000000000000000, d=1.5000000000000000000000000
b=0.2500000000000000000000000, d=1.2500000000000000000000000
...
b=0.0000000000000004440892099, d=1.0000000000000004440892099
b=0.0000000000000002220446049, d=1.0000000000000002220446049
b=0.0000000000000001110223025, d=1.0000000000000000000000000
b=0.0000000000000000555111512, d=1.0000000000000000000000000
...
b=0.0000000000000000001084202, d=1.0000000000000000000000000
b=0.0000000000000000000542101, d=1.0000000000000000000000000
```

Why does `a + b != a` have a different behavior than `d = a+b`

It looks like some operation is done with 64 bits instead.

If I repeat it with the `float64` equivalent type the result is (last 2 lines):

```
b=0.0000000000000002220446049, d=1.0000000000000002220446049
b=0.0000000000000001110223025, d=1.0000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Try printing `d={d!r}`.

Comment: [From the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html): `np.float128 provide only as much precision as np.longdouble, that is, 80 bits on most x86 machines and 64 bits in standard Windows builds`

Comment: Conjecture: `print (F"b={b:3.50f}, d={d:3.50f}")` is only capable of printing the values as `float64`, not `float128`. After 53 iterations, the `float128` in `d` is still not 1, but converting it to `float64` rounds to 1, and that is what is printed. After 64 iterations, `d` is 1, and the loop stops.

Comment: @KellyBundy, @eric-postpischil you are both right about the string formatting. @KellyBundy the `!r` flag made the trick. would you like to write it as an answer?. @cjr I guess I'm getting a 80 bit variable but the string formatter was casting it to a 64 bit variable. It's strange because I'm running it on a Ryzen 7 with Linux.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9d9cc5ca473d52eeda693a254fc0a1cbd4f4f1c4/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L303-L307) "TODO" comment in the NumPy source. (This is in the implementation of `float128.__format__`. tl;dr - it first converts the underlying C `long double` to a `double`, and then hands that off to Python's built-in `float` formatting.) See also https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10645, which is principally about formatting of `float32`, but the cause of the issue is the same - it's _also_ converted to a Python `float` before formatting.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I see the issue you linked dates from 2018. Luckily I can use the `!r` flag which provides more precision.